# Add more storage on a Amazon Web Service emulator for Windows on Mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, windows-server-2019

I'm using the Amazon Web Services emulator EC2 to run Windows server. I upgraded my instance type to the one with 4cores 16gb ram, and it worked well, but I need more storage to install visual studio. When I tried to upgrade to m5ad.xlarge to get the 150gb SSD, C: drive didn't expand like it was supposed to. I also tried adding a Volume, but that wouldn't work either. If anyone could give me a simple way or any external tutorials to complete this, that would be much appreciated, as the AWS Documentation solutions didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: You have to expand your partition as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-ebs-root-volume-windows/). Also you need to be more specific. Terms like "wouldn't work either" don't mean much. Why didn't work? Did you get any errors? What exactly did you try?

Comment: Thanks that link worked perfectly! Sorry for the bad clarification im new.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was that the **partition was not expanded**. Following steps from the following AWS blog solved the problem:

- [How do I expand the Amazon EBS root volume of my Amazon EC2 Windows instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-ebs-root-volume-windows/)